# Как распарсить многоуровневую XML таблицу в DataGridView?

Tags: c#, xml, datagridview

Есть XML такого вида

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Самым простым способом пытаюсь добавить его в DataGridView

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    XmlReader xmlFile;
    xmlFile = XmlReader.Create("1.xml", new XmlReaderSettings());
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    ds.ReadXml(xmlFile);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
}
```

Вылетает исключение из-за вложенности detail.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как передать весь Xml в DataGridView?

Comment: Ну, странный xml, да. Но скорее всего его просто можно десереализовать о объектную модель, и потом прикрутить это всё к контролу.

Comment: В каком виде хотите получить данные из представленного xml? Из того куска, что видно, должны получиться две строки `detail` или много?

Comment: Предполагаю, что следует использовать классическую схему Master-Detail. В одной таблице - список категорий: "датчик включения вентилятора", "фильтр масляный", - а в другой, список предметов в категории.

Comment: У вас detail внутри detail, вам нужно десериализовать на 2 сущности: detail и replacement и выбирать какую из них прикручивать в таблице.

Comment: Ну что там? Вы определились, какие именно данные нужно извлечь из этого xml?